# How to filter data that I received from URL on my HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, json, filter

I got my html page with a form for filtering data that I'm getting from URL. Whatever I do to filter it I'm getting back the full data, not filtered. Since I'm new in all of this, I'm not sure is this even the right approach..I want to filter_like them by title and/or action

Here is my HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>ToDoList</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="forma">
        <form class="filter-form" id="fForm">
            <input type="text" name="title_like">

            <select name="action">
                <option value="WORK">Work</option>
                <option value="SPORT">Sport</option>
                <option value="SHOPING">Shopping</option>
                <option value="MUSIC">Music</option>
            </select>  
            <button class="submit">GO</button>

            
        </form>

        
        <div class="list" id="list"></div>
        
    </div>
    
   

    
</body>
</html>
<script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
```

And here is my javascript :

```
const getTodos = (callback) => {

    // Create an XMLHttpRequest object
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();


request.addEventListener('readystatechange', () => {

    //console.log(request, request.readyState);

    if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200){

        const data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        callback(undefined, data);
    } else if(request.readyState === 4){

        callback('could not fetch data', undefined);

    }
});


request.open('GET', 'https://my-json-server.typicode.com/nebojsazr/todo_service/todos/');
request.send();

};

getTodos((err, data) => {

    if(err){
        console.log('cb fired')
    } else {

        
        
           //const sredjenadata = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2);
            document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2);
        
        
    }



});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Lets Rewrite it in a modern way

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Fetch Items</title>
    <script defer src="main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Fetch Items</h1>
    <main>
      <form id="filter-form">
        <input
          type="text"
          name="search"
          id="searchbar"
          placeholder="Search Title"
        />
        <select name="category" id="category">
          <option value="WORK">Work</option>
          <option value="SPORT">Sport</option>
          <option value="SHOPPING">Shopping</option>
          <option value="MUSIC">Music</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Fetch Again</button>
      </form>
      <ul id="result-list"></ul>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
// API URL
const API_URL = `https://my-json-server.typicode.com/nebojsazr/todo_service/todos/`;
// Get all DOM elements
const resultList = document.querySelector("#result-list");
const searchbar = document.querySelector("#searchbar");
const category = document.querySelector("#category");
const filterForm = document.querySelector("#filter-form");
// Get all the results array from api
const getResults = async () => {
  try {
    resultList.innerHTML = "Loading Data...";
    const result = await fetch(API_URL);
    const data = await result.json();
    resultList.innerHTML = "";
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
// generate output
const renderResults = (arr) =>
  arr.forEach(
    ({ title, action }) =>
      (resultList.innerHTML += `<li>${title} (${action})</li>`)
  );
// Create separate function to handle filter
const handleFilter = async () => {
  const searchText = searchbar.value;
  const selectedCategory = category.value;
  const resultsArray = await getResults();
  const arr = resultsArray
    .filter((item) =>
      item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
    )
    .filter((item) =>
      item.action.toLowerCase().includes(selectedCategory.toLowerCase())
    );
  renderResults(arr);
};
// Fetch When Form submit
filterForm.addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  handleFilter();
});
// Add onchange event on searchbar
searchbar.addEventListener("change", handleFilter);
// Add onchange event on searchbar
category.addEventListener("change", handleFilter);
// Fetch all items when dom loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {
  const arr = await getResults();
  renderResults(arr);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is working perfect, just what I needed! I thought this process is much more simple to be honest. Time to dig in and understand everything. Once again, thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm very happy that it is working for you